# What does 炎影の旅路 translates to?

Tags: words

Original Japanese: 4月2日（火）、『ファイナルファンタジーXIV』と『ファイナルファンタジーXVI』のクロスオーバークエスト「炎影の旅路」を公開予定です！ふたつの異なる世界が交わる物語に加え、多数の報酬が登場します。詳細は今後の発表にご期待ください

I was reading the news on Famitsu. There I encountered this term. I could not get the correct name of the game (炎影の旅路).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the name of a game but the name of an upcoming event quest of FFXIV. The official English translation of 炎影の旅路 is [**The Path Infernal**](https://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/special/ffxvi/).

旅路 is just "path (of a journey)" or just "journey". 炎影 is not a word listed in a dictionary but a made-up word. The literal interpretation is simply "flame shadow", and there's nothing more.

Comment: Thank you @naruto